# Are gls and dynlm calls technically different (not speaking of the stats sense)?

Tags: r, plyr

I wrote a small function to run multiple univariate regressions with different lags:

```
f <- function(x,l) {
lm.obj <- dynlm(GNP~L(get(as.character(x)),l),
              data=longley)
names(lm.obj$coefficients)[2] <- paste(x,l,sep=".")
return(lm.obj)
}
```

this works quite well with `mlply` after creating a frame of possible lag - variable combinations using `expand.grid`. A reproducible example using the `longley` dataset from the `datasets` package looks like this:

```
data(longley)
require(plyr)
vars <- expand.grid(x=names(longley)[-c(1:3)],l=1:3)

regressionList <- mlply(vars,f, .progress= "text")
summaries <- lapply(regressionList,summary)
```

This works quite well. However now I try to do the same thing using gls.

```
require(nlme)

f.gls <- function(x,l) {
gls.obj <- gls(GNP~lag(get(as.character(x)),-l),
              data=longley)
names(gls.obj$coefficients)[2] <- paste(x,l,sep=".")
return(gls.obj)
}
```

But all I get is this error:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`

I tried to use `debug()` but everything on the inside seems the same. I als tried to call the function outside `mlply` but it did not work. Also tried with out lags. It's just that x can"t be found.

Comment: you probably want something like `f <- as.formula(paste("depvar~lag(",x,",-1)")); gls(f,...)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was so mad, it did not work that I forgot about as.formula. Thanks for the reminder! Do you have any idea why it works we dynlm but not with gls?

Comment: As I'm sure you know, you can always consult the source and look for key differences.

Comment: @Chase, good point. I was just asking whether someone had already wondered and done that for me. since debug() did not really help me... I am not too optimistic about the source, but I guess I should give it a try.

Comment: evaluating the variables within formulas is tricky and fragile.  It's mildly, but not very, surprising that what you want works in `dynlm` and not in `gls` ...

Comment: actually not quite reproducible, I think -- have you tried it?  I had trouble with `mydata`, then with `depvar` ...

Comment: oups.sorry! edited that. Thanks for the note.